# Using gsub in array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, gsub

I want to remove the spaces in the key value in the hashes

```
output = [
  {"first name"=> "george", "country"=>"Australia"},
  {"second name"=> "williams", "country"=>"South Africa"},
  {"first name"=> "henry", "country"=>"US"}]
```

I was able to manage when only one hash was there inside the array with the following code

```
    Array.wrap({}.tap do |hash|
     output.each do |key|
      key.each do |k, v|
       hash[k.gsub(" ","_")] = v
      end
     end
    end)
```

Please help me to modify the array containing more than one hash.

Note: the output value is dynamic that we cannot hardcode the hash key in the code.

Comment: The mentioned array didn't work well with the code

Comment: It worked only with [{"first name" => "George", "country" => "Australia"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If hash is not nested - you can simply

```
output.map{|h| h.each_pair.map{|k,v| [k.gsub(' ', '_'), v]}.to_h }
```

Comment: The whole hash is array wrapped

Comment: Please note that it is an array of hashes

Comment: user3636388, I expect @Vasfed realized that, but the essence of the question is how to "remove spaces" in a hash's keys. Once you know how to do it for one hash, you obviously would just map the array, converting each (hash) element. The question would have been better had you confined it to a single hash. You are new to Ruby, however, so it's understandable that you didn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that will change the spaces to underscores for each key in a hash:

```
output.flat_map { |h| h.map { |key, v| { key.gsub(" ", "_") => v } } }
=> [{"first_name"=>"george"}, {"country"=>"Australia"}, {"second_name"=>"williams"}, {"country"=>"South Africa"}, {"first_name"=>"henry"}, {"country"=>"US"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify a hash's keys. You must remove the unwanted key and add a new one. Here's a way of doing both operations in one step (see the doc [Hash#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete)):

```
def convert(h) 
  h.keys.each { |k| (h[k.tr(' ','_')] = h.delete(k)) if k =~ /\s/ }
  h
end
```

Hence:

```
output.map { |h| convert h }
  #=> [{"country"=>"Australia", "first_name"=>"george"},
  #    {"country"=>"South Africa", "second_name"=>"williams"},
  #    {"country"=>"US", "first_name"=>"henry"}]
```

I've used the method [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) to convert spaces to underscores, but you could use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) as well.  Also, you could write `k.include?(' ')` rather than `k =~ /\s/`.